# Sistema de login en Laravel sin usar el nativo de Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, login, permisos

¿Qué tal?

Estoy montando una aplicación con PHP puro (dominio) a la que le he metido una capa de Laravel para utilizar ciertas cosas.

Estoy diseñando la arquitectura para que la APP esté lo más desacoplada posible del Laravel.

Ahora me encuentro en la situación de gestionar el sistema de login y autentificación, y me gustaría no tener que utilizar el propio de Laravel (ya que ello me implicaría cambiar el formato de mis clases).

Es posible crear un sistema de login en PHP puro y que se entienda con el sistema de login de Laravel? o bien, daría algún problema si me desentiendo del sistema de Login de Laravel y tiro con el legacy en PHP? Sí me gustaría luego poder utilizar las funciones de Laravel para el control de los usuarios logados, claro.

Gracias!

Comment: Cuando dices desacoplado de laravel a que te refieres?
 Sinceramente no creo que tenga sentido incluir laravel sin utilizar laravel. Respecto a Auth de laravel no tienes por qué utilizarla para el login, puedes construir algo propio.

Comment: Bien puedes hacer un login con php puro a tu gusto, utilizando los `Controladores`, `Modelos` y `Rutas` que te ofrece laravel, pero en lo que a mi concierne preferiría usar el login que da Laravel y modificar el CSS para que se vea a mi manera, ya que el Auth de Laravel da muchas opciones de seguridad en el formulario de login como también en el de registro, ya si quieres cambiar el modelo de la base de datos solo es agregar lo que deseas, es muy simple la verdad. Espero mi comentario te deje tomar la decisión mas acertada para tu proyecto, éxitos!

Comment: @Xerif la intención es poder tener el dominio de negocio lo máximo desacoplado de laravel, para que en un futuro, si se ha de mover la aplicación, no suponga un quebradero de cabeza. De Laravel solo me interesa en el enrutamiento y controladores, pero todo el negocio y repositorios lo tengo extraído de él.